# Flickering in a 2d ascii project

Tags: python, terminal, ascii

Im working on a 2d ascii rendering system it flickers a LOT
Im wondering if theres a way to decrease it a little bot,
ive tried checking if the frame is not the same as the last one but couldnt get that to work

heres the code:

```
import os
screen = []

def setScreen(x, y, c="#"):
    global screen
    screen = []
    for i in range(y):
        screen.append([])
        for j in range(x):
            screen[i].append(c)

def render():
    global screen
    line = ""
    for x in range(len(screen)):
        line2 = ""
        for y in range(len(screen[x])):
            line2 += screen[x][y]
        line+=line2+"\n"
    os.system('cls')
    print(line)

def draw(x, y, c):
    if x >= 0 and x < len(screen[0]) and y >= 0 and y < len(screen):
        screen[y][x] = c
```

Comment: Can you provide the driver code - the one which is calling these functions - so others can actually test if it is flickering?

Comment: Using `os.system('cls')` flickering is unavoidable. Look for libraries that allow you to write to positions on the console other than the current line - although such libraries may not work for all consoles.